# Why won't the success:function(result) parameter on my AJAX call activate?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am pretty new to web programming and I am trying to get a php call from another location to return values to my `AJAX` which will print onto the html via a `<pre>` tag within `<div>`.
However, despite the code seeming 100% correct, I cannot pin down the exact issue that results in the problem, as the php functions as intended, yet it does not execute the success condition, nor produce an error.
Any help would be much appreciated
This is the php code:

```
<html>
<body>
        <?php
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
            if($_GET["command"] == "write"){
                $handle = fopen("homework_10.txt", "w");
                fwrite($handle, $_GET["data"]);
            }
            if($_GET["command"] == "read"){
                $handle = fopen("homework_10.txt", "r");
                $printData = fread($handle, filesize("homework_10.txt"));
                echo json_encode($printData);
            }
}
        ?>
</body>
<html>
```

And below is the html file with the AJAX that processes the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homework 10</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button:contains('Read')").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
            url:'Link to php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { command: 'read' },
            contentType:"application/json",
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
                                $("#result").html("<pre>" + jsonData  + "</pre>");
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                                console.log(error);
                        }
           });
                });
                $("button:contains('Write')").click(function() {
                    var dataToWrite = $("#answer").val();
//"link to php is a placeholder for the purpose of posting, the actual file has a functional link to the php";
                    $.ajax({
            url: 'link to php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { command: 'write', data: dataToWrite },
            contentType:"application/json",
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
                $("#result").html("<pre>Information written to file</pre>");
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
           });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="PHP input">
            <label id="fnlabel">Type file input here:</label>
        <input id = answer type="text" name="fninput"/>
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="write">Read</button>
        <button type="button">Write</button>
        </form>
        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by sensibly formatting your code, currently it’s unnecessarily difficult to follow.  Then determine which AJAX operation shown that you’re even referring to.  From there, now is a great time to start using your browser’s debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the console?  Is the AJAX call made in the network tab?  Is the response what you expect?  In the script debugger, when you place breakpoints in the success and error callbacks, what happens?

Comment: Well, the issues occurs with both of the AJAX operations first off. The only thing that appears in the console for both of the commands is {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: f, getAllResponseHeaders: f, setRequestHeader: f, overrideMimeType: f, ...}, nothing that strikes me as an error, and the network tab shows both the php calls as valid, yet no AJAX call appears. I'll update the information on the script debugger later, it is sadly stored on a drive that I cannot access at home easily. Also I apologize for the naivety, my instructor never covered AJAX formatting or browser debugging tools.

Comment: What you're seeing there by the looks of it is the output of `console.log(error);` which isn't actually that useful. So I'd be surprised if no AJAX call appears in the Network tool. You can (at least in Chrome) tell which ones are AJAX because they say "xhr" in the "type" column. So if you see an XHR call to one of your PHP scripts, you can click on it, then click on the Response tab within it, and that will tell you exactly what reply PHP gave (if any). You can also look at the Headers to see what the Status Code of the response was (if it's not 200 OK then you have an issue)

Comment: ADyson, I just checked the output, it does show xhr, and the response does contain the contents of the file, though it does show the error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data, I imagine because the response is also sending some html tags with it for some reason, but the Id's are 200 for both commands, which leads to me being confused, it seems like it works but also doesnt

Comment: @wshoooooooo: If the response isn’t JSON then that explains the error.  The “dataType: ‘json’” setting tells jQuery to expect JSON from the server, and it fails when trying to parse data that is not JSON.  Either the server needs to return valid JSON or the client needs to expect what the server does return.

Comment: _"I imagine because the response is also sending some html tags with it for some reason"_ - the "some reason" being, that _you_ wrote them into that file, before you even start with the first `<?php` tag. And unless by any chance output buffering was active, this should get you "headers already sent" errors as well.